# Evaluation of procedural types using properties of an interface as inputs

Tags: typescript, types, interface, evaluation

I thought I knew why the following code failed to compile ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG0CuA7A1ug9gd3QF0oAyKAbylEgC4oNt90oBfAbgCgOBLdYCAE4AzAIYBjaABIAWoJwBnKBAAe-dABNFcSBQ5R9VeHVkCFAHmAALbvOQAGQgD4OLLtWgnzAOQA0UAEpKqhAaigy4BMjESFGOUAh6Bl5BapoByADkADYhAOZWGcQA-AFQxnLyZr4odn4AdA3+TmxAA)):

```js
type Type = [unknown] & { type: unknown };

interface $Zeros extends Type {
//        ~~~~~~
// Type instantiation is excessively deep...
    type: Zeros<this[0]>
}

type Zeros<N, R extends unknown[] = []> =
    N extends R['length'] ? R : Zeros<N, [0, ...R]>;
```

The problem is supposedly that `this[0]` is `unknown`, so TS tries to expand `Zeros<unknown>` and it recurs indefinitely because of the way I phrased the conditional in `Zeros`.

It was my assumption because flipping the conditional defuses it ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG0CuA7A1ug9gd3QF0oAyKAbylEgC4oNt90oBfAbgCgOBLdYCAE4AzAIYBjaABIAWoJwBnKBAAe-dABNFcSBQ5R9VeHVkCFAHmAALbvOQAGQgD4OLLtWgnzAOQA0UAEpKqhAaigy4BMjESFGOUAh6Bv7IAOQANiEA5lYpxCpqmlBeUAD8AVDGcvJmvih2fgB0Tf5ObEA)):

```js
// no error with this implementation
type Zeros<N, R extends unknown[] = []> =
    R['length'] extends N ? R : Zeros<N, [0, ...R]>;
```

But, when I swap the implementation of `Type` for the following one, I don't get this error any more:

```js
type Type = { 0: unknown, type: unknown }
```

I can even query the value directly with no problem:

```js
type GetZeros = ($Zeros & [3])['type'];
```

However, if I extract this logic in a type, then it does not compile any more (and the cure, flipping the condition in `Zeros`, is the same):

```js
type apply<$T extends Type, Args> = ($T & Args)['type'];

type applyZeros = apply<$Zeros, [3]>;
//                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type instantiation is excessively deep...
```

([playground of the aforementioned setup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8oAYBcUCuA7A1rgPYDuuANFKJFnoablAL4BQLAlrsBAE4BmAQwDG0ACQAtXkQDOUCAA9uuACay4kFCyjaq8LJJ4yAPMAAW7aQG00AXQB8LVi2rQDxgHKUASnMUQVsnTEZJY2UEihduFaOu6+SqpQXpYA5AA2-gDmZilhAPxJUPpS0kaeUNaUAHQ1XvYA3DHaAPTNSakZuNmmufH+iXEFPsWGpeWVUDVVdXb1UK1Q0gIAttBC2DwQbC5QAOIQwG6ySAAUEiVQAGQVAMw2AJSpLrmNLAsKwDzCwFSm0PuHC5pIiZdhCZzwKACMBgNIgIyiGB9AKweCUACCPEy0iip0RVygmOxjxSzxsrx20NhICO4ShMLhCKOlEsd1mQA))

I am just as surprised by the behaviour of that last snippet: I would expect `this[0]` to be `3`, so `Zeros` should be fed with `3` and `N extends R['length']` should be `3 extends R['length']`, so there should not be an infinite recursion...

Clearly, my mental model is failing me at 2 distinct spots in this example. I need some insight. **What is really happening?**

### To add some context

The above are a simplified versions of 2 designs I experimented in a [library](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types). The `{ 0: unknown, type: unknown }` implementation has many advantages and is the one I am currently using, but I preferred the behaviour of `[unknown] & { type: unknown }` when it comes to this kind of error because it helps users find the cause of the error more easily, and also sooner.

In the normal course of the usage of the library, `$Zeros['type']` should be queried by other types (to check if it can compose) even though no "argument" has been applied, so it is important that the case where `this[0]` is `unknown` (or some type constraint) and potential issues such as infinite recursion or useless/degenerate return types are handled by the implementer.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, but what's the question?

Comment: I hear you. "How is this setup really evaluated?", "Why, truly, does it not compile" is not a reasonable question for everyday users, but I would accept an imperfect model which would account for this edge case and would allow me to make further progress. I got no answer from the Typescript community on Discord. The next step would be an issue on Github. Trick questions like this on Stack Overflow are sometimes blessed with an underground black magic explanation from people like jcalz, so I give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, bellow is an explanatory model that is not canon but works well enough for me. I would be happy to be contradicted.

### The premature evaluation when `Type` is a tuple

In the code bellow, the `type` field in the interface `$Zeros` is not evaluated

```js
type Type = { 0: unknown, type: unknown }

interface $Zeros extends Type {
    type: Zeros<this[0]>
}
```

However, it gets evaluated with this single change:

```js
type Type = { [x: number]: unknown, 0: unknown, type: unknown }
```

The intersection type `[unknown] & { type: unknown }` causes the addition of an index signature, as can be demonstrated with the code bellow:

```js
type Type = Compute<[unknown] & { type: unknown }>
type Compute<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
```

The rationale is that when an interface includes an index signature, the type checker is not able to make assumptions about the properties that are present on the object, so in the case of `$Zeros`, it can't be sure that the field `0` exists or what its type is, even though the key `0` is explicitly present in the definition of `Type`, which this interface extends. Consequently TS has to evaluate the `type` field to ensure that it is well-formed.

A way to try to demonstrate this is to remove the index signature with a utility type

```js
type Type = RemoveIndex<Compute<[unknown] & { type: unknown }>>
type Compute<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type RemoveIndex<T> = {
  [ K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K ] : T[K]
};
```

Then one would need to change the definition of `$Zeros` slightly because, without the index signature, arrays can only be indexed with string keys:

```js
interface $Zeros extends Type {
    type: Zeros<this['0']>;
}
```

The above does not trigger the infinite recursion error.

### The error when the utility type `apply` is used

```js
type apply<$T extends Type, Args> = ($T & Args)['type'];

type applyZeros = apply<$Zeros, [3]>;
//                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type instantiation is excessively deep...
```

It is possible to observe that the correct return type (`[0, 0, 0]`) is inferred by hovering over `applyZeros` in the playground, so it is not the inference engine that triggers the error.

The culprit is the type checker, as it proceeds to check `$T extends Type` with `$T = $Zeros`.

Indeed, the following implementations of `apply` don't exhibit the problem:

```js
// no type constraint
type apply<$T, Args> = ($T & Args)['type' & keyof $T];

// shallow type constraint checking only the keys
type apply<$T extends (keyof $T extends keyof Type ? unknown : never), Args> =
    ($T & Args)['type' & keyof $T];
```

My understanding is that the type constraint `$T extends { type: unknown }` causes the type checker to evaluate `Zeros<this[0]>` as `Zeros<unknown>`, which leads to infinite recursion.

I believe this evaluation is not necessary because `T extends unknown` is always true and because a check that is always true can be skipped. Instead of evaluating the type, I believe that simply checking that the key exists should be enough.

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52356)